# correcting aiming animation

Tags: armature

First, sorry if question is quite noob, but I am myself.
I have an character with some pistol shooting animations but when attaching a gun, aiming is moving far from desired target.

Scene is the rigged character, and I've attached a pistol to hand bone and a thin cylinder to see the aiming area. Also, I've placed an empty that should be where the pistol is aiming in any moment.

The point is that I cannot imagine how to do it. I've tryed messing with IK and constrains, but with no success.

So any advise (for dummies) would be very appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one way doing this is like this:

1. create a new bone which has a track to constraint to your target, no parent
2. bone parent the gun to that bone

[image]

3. give another bone (maybe from the arm) an IK with that new bone as controller

[image]

then you will get this:

[image]